# Add Edit and Delete info from jtable to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtable

I'm trying to save or delete info type into this table to the database. When I run this code I just keep getting the error and I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong. The frame opens and when you put in the ID as specified by the code corresponding with what you want to change it still isn't changing.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

class Changeadd {
JFrame f;
JPanel p1, p2, p3;
JTabbedPane tp;
ImageIcon btnimg1, btnimg2;
JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10;
JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5, tf6, tf7, tf8, tf9, tf10;
JScrollPane sp1;
JButton savebtn, resetbtn, editbtn1, editbtn2, deletebtn;

Changeadd() {
    f = new JFrame("Form");
    p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2));
    p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2));
    p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    tp = new JTabbedPane();
    l1 = new JLabel("MenuID");
    l2 = new JLabel("Name");
    l3 = new JLabel("Info");
    l4 = new JLabel("Price");
    l5 = new JLabel("Enter Menu ID to delete");

    l7 = new JLabel("MenuID");
    l8 = new JLabel("Name");
    l9 = new JLabel("Info");
    l10 = new JLabel("Price");
    tf1 = new JTextField(12);
    tf2 = new JTextField(12);
    tf3 = new JTextField(12);
    tf4 = new JTextField(12);
    tf5 = new JTextField(12);
    tf6 = new JTextField(12);
    tf7 = new JTextField(12);
    tf8 = new JTextField(12);
    tf9 = new JTextField(12);
    tf10 = new JTextField(12);
    savebtn = new JButton(" Add ");
    resetbtn = new JButton(" Reset");
    editbtn1 = new JButton(" Edit ");
    editbtn2 = new JButton(" Save");
    deletebtn = new JButton("Delete");
    p1.add(l1);
    p1.add(tf1);
    p1.add(l2);
    p1.add(tf2);
    p1.add(l3);
    p1.add(tf3);
    p1.add(l4);
    p1.add(tf4);
    p1.add(savebtn);
    p1.add(resetbtn);

    p2.add(l7);
    p2.add(tf7);
    p2.add(l8);
    p2.add(tf8);
    p2.add(l9);
    p2.add(tf9);
    p2.add(l10);
    p2.add(tf10);
    p2.add(editbtn1);
    p2.add(editbtn2);

    p3.add(l5);
    p3.add(tf5);
    p3.add(deletebtn);
    resetbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            tf1.setText("");
            tf2.setText("");
            tf3.setText("");
            tf4.setText("");
        }
    });
    savebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String value1 = tf1.getText();
            String value2 = tf2.getText();
            String value3 = tf3.getText();
            String value4 = tf4.getText();
            Connection con = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
            String db = "myDB";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "root";
            System.out.println(value1 + value2 + value3 + value4);
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement st = con
                        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO menu(menu.menuID,menu.name,menu.info,menu.price) values(?,?,?,?)");
                st.setString(1, value1);
                st.setString(2, value2);
                st.setString(3, value3);
                st.setString(4, value4);
                st.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p1,
                        "Data is successfully inserted into database.");
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p1,
                        "Error in submitting data!");
            }
        }
    });

    deletebtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            String value1 = tf5.getText();
            Connection con = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
            String db = "myDB";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "root";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement st = con
                        .prepareStatement("DELETE FROM menu WHERE menu.menuID = ?");
                st.setString(1, value1);
                st.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p3,
                        "Record is deleted successfully.");
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception exp3) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p3,
                        "Error in deleting record.");
            }
        }
    });
    editbtn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            String value = tf7.getText();
            Connection con = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
            String db = "myDB";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "root";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement st = con
                        .prepareStatement("SELECT FROM menu WHERE menu.menuID=?");
                st.setString(1, value);
                ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();
                res.next();
                tf7.setText(Integer.toString(res.getInt(1)));
                tf8.setText(res.getString(2));
                tf9.setText(res.getString(3));
                tf10.setText(Integer.toString(res.getInt(4)));
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p2, "Can not edit data");
            }
        }
    });
    editbtn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Connection con = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
            String db = "myDB";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "root";
            try {
                int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(p2,
                        "Confirm edit? All data will be replaced");
                if (x == 0) {
                    try {
                        String value1 = tf7.getText();
                        String value2 = tf8.getText();
                        String value3 = tf9.getText();
                        String value4 = tf10.getText();

                        Class.forName(driver);
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user,
                                pass);
                        ;
                        Statement st = con.createStatement();
                        st.executeUpdate("UPDATE menu set menu.name'"
                                + value2 + "', menu.info'" + value3
                                + "', menu.price'" + value4
                                + "' where menu.menuID='" + value1 + "'");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p2,
                                "Updated successfully");
                        con.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p2,
                                "Error in updating edit fields");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(p2, "Error");
            }
        }
    });
}

void dis() {
    f.getContentPane().add(tp);
    tp.addTab("Add Record", p1);
    tp.addTab("Edit Record", p2);
    tp.addTab("Delete Record", p3);

    f.setSize(350, 180);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(true);
}

public static void main(String z[]) {
    Changeadd pro = new Changeadd();
    pro.dis();
}
```

}

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your url is wrong

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
```

already contains mydb appended

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
```

will pass

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbmyDB"
```

also

You have to put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` file inside the folder:

```
YOUR_WEBAPPS_FOLDER/YOUR_WEBAPP/WEB-INF/lib/
```

so that it will be available in the classpath when your servlet is compiled by the web container.

Comment: wow I can't believe I did that...started on a new project and forgot to add my bin files...thanks. My brain must be fried from doing this all day all week.